# Script detecting missing articles (a, the) in an English (command line tool for Linux)

Tags: linux, command-line, spell-checker, grammar

Is there some existing offline tool that can be pointed to a file with English text and will complain about missing "a" "the" within the text?

Preferably it would be

- command line tool (though GUI is also OK)
- working on Linux
- open source project
- active project

Yes, I am aware about G******** (one that keeps appearing in Youtube ads) but I prefer to avoid it for multiple reasons (for private text I prefer to not leak it outside, unable to automate it, requires to be online to work, using it supports ads)

Comment: What research have you done? What tools have you evaluated and rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just install [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) and use the grammar check from there?

This will allow you to parse `.doc` and many others.

If you strictly want to use the command line go for:

- [pylanguagetool](https://www.starryhope.com/notes/check-spelling-from-the-linux-command-line/)
- [LanguageTool](https://linuxhint.com/grammar-spell-check-apps-linux/)

...and Google the rest...

Comment: I though that aspell is for spellchecking? You link also mentions only typos and there is no mention of grammar checks. `aspell -?` mentions only spellchecking.